# Django Translation not working even with LOCALE_PATHS

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation

So I'm using django 1.8 to create a new web site that has to be translated into portuguese.

So to use django's own tools I added to my middlewares:

```
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
```

I also added to my context_processors:

```
'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
```

and the i configure my language settings:

```
USE_I18N = True
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
print LOCALE_PATHS
LANGUAGES = (
    ('pt-br', gettext('Portuguese')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

I also have imported on the top of my document:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

Then i added the tags:

```
{% trans "text" %}
```

on my templates with the appropriate texts. After that i ran:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l pt-br
```

then i translated everything on my .po file, and finally i compiled it with:

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

But when I ran my site it was still in english.
My Browser is on pt-br, and i also have a working example but this specific site is not being translated.
I did add the i18n urls.

Can anybody help me out? What Am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So Apparently Django has to see the locale folder as pt_br not pt-br, but the settings have to be with pt-br. That's that did the trick for me.

Comment: I let the all the code with `pt-br` as you said, but used 
`python manage.py makemessages -l pt_br` and
`python manage.py compilemessages -l pt_br`. It worked. Thanks! :)