# Django i18n only pt_pt and pt_br does not work

Tags: django, internationalization

I have a project that is translated to a lot of languages, among them `zh_hans`, `en_us` and `en_gb`. These languages work fine but for some reason `pt_pt` and `pt_br` translations do not work at all, although the "search" button is translated to "pesquisar", so probably only my locale files are not read.

Strangely, the languages work fine in local development in unix, they only don't work on the linux server.
Where can I debug this? What could be the problem?

**Specs**

My linux server is debian 10, but I have the same gettext version (0.20.1) after installing gettext using wget.
I use requirements.txt in virtualenv. There's a minor difference between my pythons: on localdev I have 3.7.4 whereas on the server I have python 3.7.3.

Comment: i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32402980/11225821) might answer you question

Comment: Thanks, it didn't fix the situation for me:(